# Can I change custom attribute scope from Global to Website so it does not appear in my second store?

Tags: scope

I do not want the custom attribute "SCOTT#" which is currently in use in my live Magento store to appear in a second store I am setting up.

If I change the scope of this attribute "Global" to "Website", will I lose all the data I currently have on my live website?

(I will only make this change if it will not affect the attribute in my current live site, as it is critical for that site's operation.)